# HashMap values getting reinitialized in a loop

Tags: java, collections, arraylist, hashmap

Here's my code.

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {                
        ArrayList<Integer> temp = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        HashMap<Integer, ArrayList<Integer>> map = new HashMap<Integer, ArrayList<Integer>>();
        int serialno = 0;

        for (int i = 1000; i < 1004; i++) {
            temp.clear();

            temp.add(i);
            temp.add((i+1000));

            map.put(serialno++, temp);
        }
        System.out.println(map);
    }
}
```

I want the output to be

```
{0=[1000, 2000], 1=[1001, 2001], 2=[1002, 2002], 3=[1003, 2003]}
```

But I'm getting the output as

```
{0=[1003, 2003], 1=[1003, 2003], 2=[1003, 2003], 3=[1003, 2003]}
```

What is happening here.? Where have I gone wrong.?

Comment: You are reusing the same hashmap, so obviously the values for any serialno will be the same.

Comment: When you `put` an object into a Map (or List), *the object does not get copied*.  Rather, the "reference" (pointer) to the object is put into the Map.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

when clearing your ArrayList `temp`, all you do is deleting it's values. however when you put the ArrayList into your map, you actually put the object reference of the ArrayList into the map and *not* a new list with new values. So in your map is four times the same ArrayList (and thus four times the same values).

```
 HashMap<Integer, ArrayList<Integer>> map = new HashMap<Integer, ArrayList<Integer>>();
 int serialno = 0;

 for (int i = 1000; i < 1004; i++) {
      ArrayList<Integer> temp = new ArrayList<Integer>();
      temp.add(i);
      temp.add((i + 1000));
      System.out.println(i + 1000);

      map.put(serialno++, temp);
 }
 System.out.println(map);
```

When you create a new List in every loop, you will actually put different ArrayLists (with different references) in the map.

Answer (score 1):

You create just one object of `ArrayList` and put it multiply times into the `HashMap` so you have many references to the same object in your `HashMap`, but you want more than one `ArrayList` object so you have to create them in your loop.

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        HashMap<Integer, ArrayList<Integer>> map = new HashMap<Integer, ArrayList<Integer>>();
        int serialno = 0;

        for (int i = 1000; i < 1004; i++) {
            ArrayList<Integer> temp = new ArrayList<Integer>();

            temp.add(i);
            temp.add((i+1000));

            map.put(serialno++, temp);
        }

        System.out.println(map);
    }
}
```

Comment: whats the difference in "temp = new ArrayList<Integer>()" and "temp.clear()"

Comment: `temp.clear()` remove the items from the same object so you got the same result, you need to create a new object on each rotation